# Load more button works just once

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table named tbl_video that  consist of two fields (video_id, video_title  What I want to add a load more button  using Ajax JQuery like social networking sites .I am able to get the first two records  but when I try second time nothing happens. I dont get any errors .What am i doing wrong .

this my index.php file I create table structure here  and then fetch two records.And get the second record's id value and send it to the more.php  file

```
  <body>  

                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="load_data_table"> 

                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <td width="15%">Video Id</td>
                    <td>Video Title</td>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $video_id = $row['video_id']; ?>
                             <tr>
                             <td><?php echo $row['video_id']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $row['video_title']; ?></td>

                             </tr>
                        <?php
                    }

                    ?> 
                    <tr id="remove_row"><td><button type="button" id="more" class="btn btn-success form-control"
                     data-id="<?php echo $video_id; ?>">More</button></td></tr>

                    </table>  
               </div>  
          </div>  
     </body>  
</html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
     $('#more').click(function(){
 var id=$(this).data("id");


        $.ajax({
            url:"more.php",
            data:{id:id},
            method:"post",
            success:function(data){

              if(data!=''){

               $('#load_data_table').append(data);
               $('#remove_row').remove();


              }
              else{
                $('#more').html("No Data");
              }
            }
```

and this the more.php file.I think it is self explanatory

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$output = '';
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testing');
$data = mysqli_query($db, "select * from tbl_video where video_id >{$id} limit 2");
if (mysqli_num_rows($data)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
        $output .= '

         <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td>'.$row['video_id'].'</td>
          <td>'.$row['video_title'].'</td>
         </tr>

         ';
    }
    $output .= '
  <tr id="remove_row"><td><button type="button" id="more" class="btn btn-success form-control"
  data-id="'.$row['video_id'].'">More</button></td></tr></tbody>

  ';
    echo $output;
}
```

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: have a look at offset in mysql. you need to pass a counter that fetch "the next two records" from the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a new row and there is a new button for More

It has the same id as the original button so there is a conflict there

also the javascript needs to be initiliazed something like this

PHP:

```
   $output .= '<tr id="remove_row"><td><button type="button"  class="more btn btn-success form-control" data-id="'.$row['video_id'].'">More</button></td></tr></tbody>';
```

Javascript:

```
<script>  
function moreButton() {
$('.more').click(function(){
var id=$(this).data("id");


$.ajax({
    url:"more.php",
    data:{id:id},
    method:"post",
    success:function(data){

      if(data!=''){

       $('#load_data_table').append(data);
       $('#remove_row').remove();

         moreButton();
      }
      else{
        $('.more:last').html("No Data");
      }
    }
 });
 }
 $(document).ready(function(){  

   moreButton();
 });
```

Don't forget to remove the id of the more button to a class with .more